# searching for 'www.' and replacing with 'http://' with regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, url, replace

I am trying to make URL's entered by a user clickable links.  Right now I have a regex searching for URL's and wrapping them in `<a>` tags.

For Example:

```
var message = 'This is a test message on http://stackoverflow.com/ forum!'
var regex = /((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/g;
message = message.replace(regex, '<a href=$1 target="_blank" class="comment-format-url">$1</a>');

//This is a test message on <a href=http://stackoverflow.com/ target="_blank" class="comment-format-url">http://stackoverflow.com/</a> forum!
```

What my current problem is that most users would type in `www.stackoverflow.com` which would give a `404` page not found error when they click.  I want to be able to check if they have entered `www.stackoverflow.com` and replace it with `http://stackoverflow.com`.

My current regex replace method looks like the following:

```
message = message.replace(/(www\.)/ig, 'http://');
```

The problem is that it will do things like this...

`https://www.opentext.com` --> `https://https://opentext.com`

How can I make it check to see if the string starts with `www.` to prevent the above from happening?

Thanks!

Comment: try `message.replace(/^www\./ig, 'http://');`

Comment: That works great except if the link is in the middle of a string.

Comment: then try this `message.replace(/(^| )www\./ig, '$1http://');`

Comment: I ended up using `/(\s|^)(www\.)/ig`

Answer (score 0):

Following regex adds `a` tags to links starting with `http(s)://`, `www.` or both:

```
message.replace(/((https?:\/\/|www\.|https?:\/\/www\.)[0-9a-z\.\-=:\/\?%&#;]+)/gi, '<a href="$1" target="_blanc">$1</a>')
```